# Variable not changing in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

(I'm kind of a beginner at programming, so sorry if the answer is obvious.)
I was trying to make a rudimentary Tetris clone on javascript, but a specific issue keeps giving me trouble. Heres all the code I have so far:

```js
var w = 10;
var h = 22;
var s = 20;
var blocks = [];
var time;
var rand;
var I = [[3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], 0, 255, 255];
var O = [[4, -1], [5, -1], [4, 0], [5, 0], 255, 255, 0];
var T = [[4, 0], [5, -1], [5, 0], [6, 0], 170, 0, 255];
var S = [[4, -1], [5, -1], [5, 0], [6, 0], 0, 255, 0];
var Z = [[4, 0], [5, 0], [5, -1], [6, -1], 255, 0, 0];
var J = [[4, -1], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], 0, 0, 255];
var L = [[4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [6, -1], 255, 165, 0];
function setup() {
 time = Number(second());
 rand = [I, O, T, S, Z, J, L];
 rand = shuffle(rand);
 createCanvas(s * w + 2, s * h + 1);
 let x = -1;
 let y = -2;
 for (i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
  x++;
  if (x > 9) {
   x = 0;
   y++;
  }
  blocks.push(new Block(x, y));
 }
 currentBlock = sevenRand();
} // does grid building
var currentBlock;
function getBlock(x, y) {
 for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  if (blocks[i].idx == x && blocks[i].idy == y) {
   return i;
  }
 }
 return false;
} // gets block number in array from x and y coordinates
function Block(x, y, idx, idy) {
 this.x = x * s;
 this.y = y * s;
 this.idx = x;
 this.idy = y;
 this.w = s;
 this.h = s;
 this.r = 255;
 this.g = 255;
 this.b = 255;
 this.update = function() {};
}
function draw() {
 empty();
 for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
  blocks[getBlock(currentBlock[n][0], currentBlock[n][1])].r = currentBlock[4];
  blocks[getBlock(currentBlock[n][0], currentBlock[n][1])].g = currentBlock[5];
  blocks[getBlock(currentBlock[n][0], currentBlock[n][1])].b = currentBlock[6];
 }
 if (time != Number(second())) {
  move();
  time = Number(second());
 }
 if (currentBlock[0][1] > 19 || currentBlock[1][1] > 19 || currentBlock[2][1] > 19 ||currentBlock[3][1] > 19) {
  currentBlock = sevenRand();
 }
 for (i = 2 * w; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  fill(blocks[i].r, blocks[i].g, blocks[i].b);
  rect(blocks[i].x, blocks[i].y, blocks[i].w, blocks[i].h);
 }
}

//block positions

//var rand = ["I", "O", "T", "S", "Z", "J", "L"];
function shuffled(array) {
 var currentIndex = array.length,
  temporaryValue,
  randomIndex;
 while (0 !== currentIndex) {
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
  currentIndex -= 1;
  temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
  array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
  array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
 }

 return array;
} //shuffles array

var n = -1;
function sevenRand() {
 n += 1;
 if (n > 6) {
  rand = shuffled(rand);
  n = 0;
 }
 return rand[n];
} //7-bag randomizer
//function collision() {}

function empty() {
 //later have to save positions of previous block
 for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].r = 255;
  blocks[i].g = 255;
  blocks[i].b = 255;
 }
}

function move() {
 for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
  currentBlock[n][1]++;
 }
} // drops the block
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

(sorry for the long code snippet)

The part I'm having trouble with is that it resets the block after it touches the ground the first time, with

```
if (
  currentBlock[0][1] > 19 ||
  currentBlock[1][1] > 19 ||
  currentBlock[2][1] > 19 ||
  currentBlock[3][1] > 19
) {
  currentBlock = sevenRand();
}
```

which creates a new block after it touches the ground, however, it fails to change the variable the second time and stops the draw loop altogether. (You can see it if you run it long enough.) I've been trying a long time to find the issue, to no avail. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Next time you post a question, please reread it first, to see if you messed up the syntax for code formatting etc. because your post was mixing proper SO code styles and github-markdown code styling. However, also please read through ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) and then notice that this much code probably includes _way_ more code than is involved in your problem. Form an [mcve], so that if you don't spot the problem yourself while forming one, you have good, concise code for others to look at and ask questions about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies within the function `sevenRand()`. The problem is that your program is directly editing the data within your `rand` variable. So that when a shape has reached the bottom of the screen it is reflected within the x and y locations within that variable. So essentially, on the third time round of executing `sevenRand()` it chooses a shape whos x and y coordinates are already at the bottom of the screen, which is why you get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'r' of undefined

A way around this would be to create a complete copy of the value within the `rand` variable so that you are not changing the values of the original. A quick way to do this would be: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rand))[n];`

Here's what  `sevenRand()` should look like:

```
function sevenRand() {
    n += 1;
    if (n > 6) {
        rand = random(rand);
        n = 0;
    }
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rand))[n]
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you very much!